# # of Represented vs. # of Responses

Tags: discussion

In "response" to [this statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229071/questions-multiple-drafts#comment751584_229071):

> @Jsh562 The few dozen users who have even acknowledged these request are nowhere near making up 0.5% of the users on SO. There are many hundreds of thousands of users. To get even 1% of the user base there would need to have thousands of people, not a dozen or so.

Just curious, is there anyone that has an idea of the approximate ratio of responses (up-votes or answers) given to a posted question vs. number of users represented by that response?

This is in regards to SE overall and not just meta or just feature-requests. Although, I believe the only real measureable data would come from feature and bug requests, the analyzed data would still apply to all of SE as an approximate statistic.

Could be a great analytic metric for SE also, if enough data is analyzed in this fashion. Sort of the same line as survey analytic/statistics I think?

Is this even an okay place to ask this question? Apologies if not.

Comment: Can you provide some context for the quoted comment?  A link, perhaps?

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229071/questions-multiple-drafts#comment751584_229071

Comment: I was meaning to try to keep WHO said the comment hidden from the public.
Any reason for wanting more context for the comment? My question pertains to something other than the context.

Comment: or Servy could just post it up for himself.

Comment: Well, without the context, it sounded like a curiosity question about how many people who encounter a particular post actually 1. Have enough rep and 2.  Care enough to vote. The rest are either 1. Casual viewers, 2.  Don't know what voting is, and/or 3.  Don't know where they are.  Now that I have some context, I realize that you're talking about ***meta feature requests.***

Comment: Oh okay. sorry. did not realize that.
Actually, I am wondering from a statistics point of view for ALL of SE. not just feature requests or just meta. But the only real MEASUREABLE data would come from feature requests (and bug requests?), i believe

Answer (score 5):

Votes on feature requests is, on the whole, a pretty terrible metric for attempting to judge how many people in the community would use that feature if it were implemented, simply because Meta isn't demographically similar to the main sites.  The meta sites are primarily populated with the most active and invested users, with occasional visits now and then from moderately active users.  Newer users and users with a minimal amount of experience with the site make up a small percentage of meta traffic, and most of that is related to bugs and support problems, rather than feature requests.  The exact opposite is the case on main sites; they are made up primarily of new and inexperienced users with a small scattering (proportionally) of intermediate/advanced users.

Feature requests on meta simply are viewed by too small of a percentage of SO's population for the votes to have a whole lot of statistical meaningfulness, except in rare cases of exceedingly popular or exceedingly unpopular ideas.  Most statements about how a feature will be used/perceived by the site's general population are conjecture that is generally not based on the polling that takes place through meta voting.

While looking at the score of requests can tell you *something* about the request, making it not entirely worthless information, it's important to keep in mind what it really represents, and understand that meaningful statistical statements just aren't going to be possible given the size of the data sets.

Comment: This is true, hadn't thought of this part yet

Comment: ^ continued: about the more seasoned users being on meta and vice versa for the other sites.
But I still thought that DUE TO the size of the data set, it will be a meaningful statistic. Is this not true?

Comment: @Jsh562 does a sample of 1 million women between 20 and 25 tell you anything about the general population; yes, but it will be skewed. Will increasing the poll size to 1 trillion help; not even slightly

Comment: I think statistical significance has more to do with that and as long as you have the minimum statistical sample size, and depending on what kind of confidence interval is chosen, you should have representative data related to the rest of the SE population. So will increasing the sample size from 1 million to 1 trillion help? probably not. but increasing from a dozen or so to hundreds? would most likely have a dramatic effect on statistical accuracy

Comment: @Jsh562 Statistics would also require the samples to be chosen at random.  That is not the case here.  Both problems contribute.  We don't have a large enough sample size for statistical significance, and they're not chosen randomly, there is a very significant bias in which people are in the sample size.  Both of these contribute to dramatically reducing (although not entirely eliminating) the probative value of votes.